# How to pass a 2-dimensional array to Etherscan?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, arrays

How do you pass a 2D array into etherscan?

This works in remix but not etherscan: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

Comment: Try it in a json like object: { [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] }

Comment: This doesn't work :-/

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x29A2C91D40Fbe67D85f322f5A2A76f145A382177#readContract